# Create column of File datatype dynamically android in parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

Generate dynamically column with file data type in parse.com using android code

```
 ParseObject tableName = new ParseObject("NewTable");
 tableName.put("columnOne", "string"); // string
 tableName.put("columnTwo", 12); // integer
 tableName.put("Filedata", ); <----------Here must be file data type
 tableName.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To store with file data type ---**

Get the data in `byte[]` form and then create a `ParseFile` with it.

In this example, we'll just use a string:

```
byte[] data = "Working at Parse is great!".getBytes();
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("filedata.txt", data);
file.saveInBackground();
```

Finally, after the save completes, you can associate a ParseFile onto a ParseObject just like any other piece of data:

```
ParseObject tableName = new ParseObject("NewTable");
tableName.put("columnOne", "string"); // string
tableName.put("columnTwo", 12); // integer
tableName.saveInBackground();
tableName.put("Filedata", file);
tableName.saveInBackground();
```

Retrieving it back involves calling one of the getData variants on the ParseObject. Here we retrieve the `Filedata` file off another object:

```
ParseFile applicantFile = (ParseFile)anotherApplication.get("Filedata");
applicantFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
  public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // data has the bytes for the resume
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

This is explained more thoroughly at [Android Parse Guide.](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide)

Comment: Hi @Ved Prakash look not like that i want to just create column with datatype named File, look here column created with entry of txt file!

Comment: we need blank column with datatype of FILE